# How can I add new array elements at the end of an array?

Tags: java

I want to add an array to another array of arrays. Can you help me?

```
 public static double[][] append(double[][] array, double[] value) {
             double[][] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + value.length);
             for(int i=0;i<value.length;i++){
             result[result.length - 1][i] = value[i];
             }
             return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only adding a single array, so change this:

```
double[][] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + value.length);
```

to this:

```
double[][] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
```

Every array is an object, even primitive arrays.  If you were to add `System.out.println(result[0].getClass().getSuperClass());` to your code, it would print `class java.lang.Object`.

This means every element of 'result' is an object.  When you call Arrays.copyOf and request a larger array, all of the extra elements are set to null (as specified in the [Arrays.copyOf documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-)).

Which means you may not legally access `result[result.length - 1][i]` until you set `result[result.length - 1]` to a non-null value.  Specifically, you want to set it to a new double array.

In Java, all arrays have a typesafe public clone() method, so you can do away with your for-loop, and simply call:

```
result[result.length - 1] = value.clone();
```

Comment: thank you so much VGR and Bubletan

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add one index to the `array`, and set its value to `value`. Currently you are trying to add the double values in an array of arrays of doubles.

```
public static double[][] append(double[][] array, double[] value) {
    array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
    array[array.length - 1] = value;
}
```